# How much rotate cylinder with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, rotation, autorotate

I have a problem with **OpenGL**. Here follows some useful data:

- Blue point is cylinder, which is looking to green reference point on
  the screen.
- Green point is first reference point
- Red point is second
  reference point.

I will change reference points with keyboard keys *h,j,k*, and *l* -by the way vim also uses these keys to navigate.

Other useful info:
First, I have changed reference points from green to red, by changing `centerx`, `centery`, `centerz` of `gluLookAt`.
Second, I want to rotate cylinder so that it will be looking to the new reference points.

How much should I rotate so that cylinder will still look at reference points?

http://www.arefs.org/projects/images/triangle-rock.png

Comment: If you have any trouble with the form or the way you can use Stackoverflow, please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: How does a cylinder look at a point?

Comment: @Max cylinder's top is looking to the reference points. And, camera position is fixed.

Comment: @Max can I explained well ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question right,

Let the vector between the old reference point and the eye be **V1**

Let the vector between the new reference point and the eye be **V2**

You can find the angle between these vectors, which is also the angle to rotate, by:

```
θ = arccos( (V1 dot V2) / |V1||V2| )
```

[image]